# Where to/ how to put the value in for a place holder, in a sSQL statement

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a sSQl statement where i want to select values from the database, based on the selected value of the drop down list.
Here is my code.

```
string sSQL = "";

        sSQL = ("Select * From tbl_TripPrefixDestination Where Country like {0}", ddlCountrySelect.SelectedItem.Text);
        sSQL += "";
        sSQL += "";

        OpenConnection(conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, conn);
```

To me this seems like the right way to do this, yet i still get errors. Can anyone please help me? ( dont mind

Comment: sSQL = ("Select * From tbl_TripPrefixDestination Where Country like {0}", ddlCountrySelect.SelectedItem.Text); Looks like you're forgetting to prepend string.Format() there. Also, if you're getting errors, don't just tell us about them, actually show us what they look like!

Comment: I hear you. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the simplest level you probably need:

```
sSQL = String.Format("Select * From tbl_TripPrefixDestination Where Country like '%{0}%'", ddlCountrySelect.SelectedItem.Text);
```

if you're doing a wild card search or

```
sSQL = String.Format("Select * From tbl_TripPrefixDestination Where Country = '{0}'", ddlCountrySelect.SelectedItem.Text);
```

for an exact match.

But you should look at the SqlParameter object:

```
sSQL = "Select * From tbl_TripPrefixDestination Where Country = @Country";
...
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@Country", ddlCountrySelect.SelectedItem.Text);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

As PaulG says, one (BIG) reason for using sqlparameter is that your database will automatically escape the data preventing injection attacks - and another is improved performance.
http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/

Comment: May be worth explaining - the parameterised query is safer (prevents malicious users from exploiting sql injection attacks) and optimises sql plan caches better.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick you explained that very well. I have gone the route of the parameter route before, but since this will be managed by the company, to produce reports and manifest. But i think it may be good practice to just use the paramter way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this

```
sSQL = String.Format("Select * From tbl_TripPrefixDestination Where Country like {0}", ddlCountrySelect.SelectedItem.Text);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So do you want your kiss now or later? (ill accept the answer in 7 minutes)

Comment: That's the right way to use String.Format(), but it's a bad way to use SQL. if `ddlCountrySelect.SelectedItem.Text` happens to be `"People's Democratic Republic of Lao"`, or if it's free text. (not my dv btw)

Comment: This is neither correct nor the best practise. Please have a look at the other answer or you'll never have a chance to learn it the right way.

Comment: Cool sorry i just saw this answer first and it gave me the results i needed